# eXist-db send JSON via POST request using eXPath Http_module

Tags: json, http, xquery, exist-db

I am trying to send JSON via a POST request from eXist-db to an API using the eXPath HTTP-Module, but I'm always recieving the following Error:

```
exerr:ERROR Error serializing the body content
```

My XQuery looks like:

```
xquery version "3.1";

declare namespace output="http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

let $payload := map {
    "name": "testuser",
    "role": "user"
  }


return

hc:send-request(
  <hc:request method='post'>
    <hc:body media-type="application/json"/>
  </hc:request>,
  'https://reqres.in/api/users',
  serialize($payload, <output:serialization-parameters>
            <output:method>json</output:method>
        </output:serialization-parameters>)
)[2] => util:base64-decode() => parse-json()
```

Expected Output (tested via Postman):

```
{
    "name": "testuser",
    "id": "820",
    "createdAt": "2021-06-03T05:50:32.049Z"
}
```

How do i serialize content to JSON and send it via a POST-request from eXist-db? The solution prompted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66225210/handle-json-only-api-with-basex-xquery-code/66225845#66225845) is not working for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to add `@method="text"` to the `<body>` element.

This attribute is documented in the EXPath HTTP Client spec, section [3.2 Serializing the request content](http://expath.org/spec/http-client#d2e362):

> The default value of the serialization method depends on the media-type: it is `xml` if it is an XML media type, `html` if it is an HTML media type, `xhtml` if it is application/xhtml+xml, `text` if it is a textual media type, and `binary` for any other case.

What this means is that the EXPath HTTP Client doesn't have a built-in mapping for the media-type of `application/json`—i.e., it falls back on `binary`. But JSON *is* a textual media type, and you've already performed the serialization of your XDM map into text via the `fn:serialize()` function. So you have to override the EXPath HTTP Client default of `method="binary"` and set `method="text"` on the `<body>` element.

The [draft v2 spec](https://expath.github.io/expath-cg/specs/http-client-2/#single-entity-body), simplifies sending JSON; by default, when it detects that the body contains a `map()` or `array()`, it will serialize the item as JSON, with the appropriate media-type.

But for now with v1, we still need to explicitly (1) serialize maps and arrays using the JSON serialization method and (2) specify `method="text"` on the `<body>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reformated version with the parameters broken out into their individual variables from Joe's answer.

```
xquery version "3.1";

let $payload := map {
    "name": "testuser",
    "role": "user"
  }
let $request := 
    <hc:request method='post'>
        <hc:body method="text" media-type="application/json"/>
    </hc:request>

let $href := 'https://reqres.in/api/users'

let $bodies := fn:serialize($payload, map { "method": "json" })
        
return

hc:send-request($request, $href, $bodies)[2] => util:base64-decode() => parse-json()
```