# Exist DB XQuery: How to make an HTTP POST Request

Tags: http-post, xquery, exist-db, exide

**Question**: How do you make an HTTP POST request to an external service within Exist DB, ideally using just XQuery?

**Motivation**: I want to take a set of XML documents in Exist DB, and send each to an external server for processing, then I want to receive the result, and store them back in Exist DB.

I can accomplish this with an external script that interacts with the Exist DB REST interface, but I would like to it all within Exist DB and XQuery. Marklogic has a http request [function that does POST requests](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:http-post) under the `xdmp` namespace, which seems to accomplish this. Does something similar exist for Exist-DB?

Bonus points if the request body can be sent in JSON format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

eXist-db implements the [EXPath HTTP Client](http://expath.org/spec/http-client) specification, which defines a function, `http:send-request`, that can perform HTTP POST requests.

For sample code, including sending a request body containing JSON, see [eXist-db send JSON via POST request using eXPath Http_module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67816128/exist-db-send-json-via-post-request-using-expath-http-module).